# ClientGroupHeaderTemplate in Excel Export (Kendo ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: css, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a grid that shows a list of financial arrears grouped by the type of debt, known as **Cash Type**. These Cash Types can be categorised in a number of ways, or not, which is "Normal". When they are categorised I'm adding a lovely badge in the ClientGroupHeaderTemplate so it stands out to the user. All good so far.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.Arrears)
    .Name("arrearsGrid-" + Model.LeaseId.ToString())
    .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "smallergrid" })
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.InvoiceNumber)
            .ClientTemplate("<a class=\"text-primary\" href=\"" + Url.Action("Invoice", "Arrear") + $"/#=InvoiceNumber#?buildingid=#=BuildingId#&leaseid={Model.LeaseId}\" target=\"_blank\">#=InvoiceNumber#</a>");
        columns.Bound(p => p.InvoiceDescription);
        columns.Bound(p => p.CashType)
            .ClientGroupHeaderTemplate("Cash Type: #= getCashTypeName(data.value) # (#= getDebtCategoryName(data.items[0].DebtCategory) #)");
        columns.Bound(p => p.InvoiceDate);
        columns.Bound(p => p.TransactionDate);
        columns.Bound(p => p.DaysOverdue);
        columns.Bound(p => p.InvoiceGross)
            .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "text-right" });
        columns.Bound(p => p.OutstandingGross)
            .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "text-right" });
    })
    .Sortable()
    .Excel(excel => excel
        .FileName("Kendo UI Grid Export.xlsx")
        .Filterable(true)
        .AllPages(true)
    )
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .ServerOperation(false)
        .Group(g => g.Add(p => p.CashType))
    )
    .NoRecords(x => x.Template("<div class='empty-grid'></div>"))
)
```

The problem is the Export to Excel function does no processing on the ClientGroupHeaderTemplate, and shows`<span>Cash Type: Rent <span class="d-print-none badge debt-category-1 ml-2">In Query</span></span>` in the spreadsheet.

Here's the options I see are available, and some I've discounted. Are these really the best options I have?

### CSS (rejected)

As you can see, using the Bootstrap `d-print-none` does nothing. From all the posts on Export and hidding columns, it seems that Kendo is in no way using a print view of the page, so `@media` options aren't going to help.

### excelExport event

Use the Kendo [excelExport](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/events/excelexport) event to [customise the generated Excel workbook](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/excel/introduction#excel-document-creation), however, this example is document creation. If I'm going this route I suspect it might be easier to write one from scratch, rather than workaround Kendo limitations. Either way it's a lot of work to remove 1 line of HTML markup.

### Use the ProxyURL

Under a Grids Excel object, you can set an endpoint to call when the Excel spreadsheet is created. This might give the chance to tweak a ready-to-save spreadsheet before it is saved. There's a demo of it [here](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/excel-export). The demo is wrong (the Controller name is not Grid, it's Excel_Export) and it doesn't work for me even when corrected and the standard `.ToolBar(tools => tools.Excel())` back in. Maybe it's because I'm not AJAXing my data in, or maybe it's just as broken as the demo. Changing my grid to AJAX will is not beyond the realms of possibility, but it's not a small job either.
**Edit:** I got this to hit the event by also adding `.ForceProxy(true)` to the Excel definition. This isn't mentioned in the demo, and the statement that you need to add `.ToolBar(tools => tools.Excel())` is also incorrect; you can fire the event from your own buttons that trigger the Excel export.

### Give up and go simple

The last option I have is to give up on the badges and just have text. It's the quickest and surest option, but it's solving the problem by ignoring the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed this in yet another way. I'm sure there must be an MVC answer to this problem though.

I added an event to my Grid

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
    ...
    .Events(e =>
    {
        e.ExcelExport("exportExcel");
    }
    ...
)
```

and created a JavaScript middleware function to alter the Excel file before it is saved. Of course you can then do whatever JS allows you to do at this point.
In the code below are examples of setting a column width (4), removing HTML span markup, and converting a string to a number and adding a currency format to that number (7). The method of obtaining the currency symbol is not pretty, but it's a string inside some HTML markup, I don't think it can be pretty.

```
function exportExcel(e) {
    var sheet = e.workbook.sheets[0];

    var lastRow = sheet.rows[sheet.rows.length - 1];
    var lastCell = lastRow.cells[lastRow.cells.length - 1];
    var lastCellValue = lastCell.value.toString().replace(/<[^>]*>/, "").replace("</span>", "");
    var currency = lastCellValue.substring(0, 1);
    currency += "#,###,##0.00";

    sheet.columns[4].autoWidth = false;
    sheet.columns[4].width = 125;

    $.each(sheet.rows, function (index, row) {
        if (index > 0) {
            if (row.cells[0] != undefined) {
                if (row.cells[0].value != undefined) {
                    row.cells[0].value = row.cells[0].value.replace(/<[^>]*>/, "(").replace("</span>", ")");
                }
            }
            if (row.cells[7] != undefined) {
                if (row.cells[7].value != undefined) {
                    row.cells[7].value = row.cells[7].value.toString().replace(/<[^>]*>/, "").replace("</span>", "");
                    row.cells[7].value = Number(row.cells[7].value.toString().replace(/[^0-9\.-]+/g, ""));
                    row.cells[7].format = currency; // Why this prepends a backslash to the format I do not know
                }
            }
        }
    });
};
```